# Identification of Electrical Component

Tags: components, identification, electrical

I'd appreciate some help identifying the component in the pictures below. The actual PCB is part of a shift interlock solenoid from an Audi A6 that went bad. I'm trying to salvage the part as it is really hard to come by.

Looks like a fuse, but if you look closely those two pins are overlapping by quite a bit and there is no sign of damage to say that it burned out. The overall circuit is quite simple, there's only a 471 ohm resistor and those two components that I'm unsure of.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) to me.  If it is a reed switch, then there should be some magnets to activate the switches in the place where it is installed -- perhaps on the shift?